# How can save the image generate to Aviary

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, aviary

I have the code

```js
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
 apiKey: 'your-client-id-here',
 theme: 'light', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
 tools: 'all',
 appendTo: '',
 onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
  var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
  img.src = newURL;
 },
 onError: function(errorObj) {
  alert(errorObj.message);
 }
});
function launchEditor(id, src) {
 featherEditor.launch({
  image: id,
  url: src
 });
 return false;
}
```

```html
<!-- Load Feather code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/imaging/v3/editor.js"></script>


<div id='injection_site'></div>

<img id='image1' src='http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg'/>

<!-- Add an edit button, passing the HTML id of the image and the public URL of the image -->
<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg');" /></p>
```

I want save the images generate to Aviary: https://s3.amazonaws.com/feather-client-files-aviary-prod-us-east-1/2016-06-06/178ba6a3-0488-4b43-b4bc-133cf499c72c.jpg and insert to MySQL.

How can take the url and insert to MysQL.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need an answer...

The function onSave will show the Amazon temporary URL for the edited image. It`s in the 'newURL' variable.

So, you can just run an Ajax call to send this to your database.

This part of code goes inside onSave function.

```
$.ajax({
   url: <url_to_your_controller>,
            type:'post',
            data: {
                image_url : newURL,
            },
            success:function() {
                alert("Yeah! We did it!")
            }
        });
```

Comment: Arceliver, Sorry not reply you.
I not fount your post.
I not have very experience with StackOverflow.com
Your solution is perfect!
Thanks to reply!